# Could not load type .... from assembly error when trying to add dll (user control)

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, user-controls, publish

I made my custom user control, so that i use it in different applications. The problem is that when i want to rename dll which i get in bin/debug ,then drag it into toolbox, i get that error:

[image]

I tried with renaming user control namespace , name and solution name, but it still generates dll with old name every time.

How to get desired new dll name and is it even possible?
It would be hard and elbow grease work if i create new control with new name and
start from beggining.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the assembly name.

In solution explorer, goto the project properties (right click on the Project -> Properties  or press Alt+Enter). Under the 'Application' tab you will see a textbox for Assembly Name.
Change the textbox value to the desired name you need. Then build the project.

Now you should have your dll with the new name.